# Decrease Font Size When Viewing on Small Screens With Tailwindcss

Tags: tailwind-css

I want to keep base font size at 1rem, and when user views on mobile (under 640px) change it to .75rem (TW .`text-sm` class)

I thought doing it this way would work but seems like it's producing the opposite effect:

```
<p class="text-base sm:text-xs">Some paragraph text</p>
```

[Codepen example here](https://codepen.io/ericnguyen23/pen/rNVXeEe)

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out. Since TW is mobile first, I had to define my base size, then target the rest:

```
<p class="text-xs sm:text-base">Some paragraph text</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

By default you design for small screen in Tailwind

Thus it must be

```
<p class="text-xs sm:text-base md:text-xl">Some paragraph text</p>
```

Comment: if u want to decrease the font more you can use `text-[0.65rem]`